# Why is it carriage and pair when you have 2 horses

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

The correct (UK) English usage is "horse and carriage", "pony and trap", etc., when you have 1 horse, "carriage and pair" for 2 or "coach and horses" for more.

I am wondering why the coach or carriage goes before the horses when there are more than one but we would never usually say "carriage and horse".

Is this just one of the peculiarities of the English language or does someone here know of a grammatical rule?

Comment: I doubt that there is a grammatical rule for it, I believe that is a convention. I suspect that the convention arose from the fact that single horse vehicles were mainly drawn by horses which had other uses such as riding, ploughing, timber dragging and so on whereas multi-horse vehicles were drawn by horses which were used for nothing else. I initially thought that it related to the class of the owner but then I thought about 'Waggon and Horses' which uses the same form.

Comment: Say "horse and carriage" and "carriage and horse".  Which seems to flow off your tongue more easily?

Comment: Besides "love and marriage goes together like a carriage and horse" doesn't rhyme very well.

Comment: @HotLicks OTOH, notice what rhymes with "divorce" :)